# To prove a given set is a $\sigma$ algebra

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

I need to prove the following

If $R$ is a $\sigma$ ring then $\{ E \subset X : E \subset R $ or $ E^c \subset R \}$ is a $\sigma$ algebra.

Here now my claim is that $E_j \in R\ \forall i = 1,2,\ldots$ then  $\bigcup E$ is countable if all $E_j \in R$ otherwise all  ${E_j}^c \in R$
But I think this is wrong. 
how should it be proved ?

Comment: You really should rephrase the last part.

Comment: Please notice my edits.  The braces in things like $\{E\subset X : \cdots\cdots\cdots \}$ should be _inside_ the MathJax tags; otherwise you get mistmatches in font and size, and lack of proper spacing. (They require backslashes.)  And \cup is used in things like $A\cup B$ and $A_1\cup\cdots\cup A_n$, whereas \bigcup is used in things like $\bigcup_{j=1}^\infty E_j$.  One thing I did not correct if about language: one says "for i=1,2,3,\ldots" or "for all i\in\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$", but one should not say "for all $i=1,2,3,\ldots$". ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: yeah. Will pay attention henceforth.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First a definition:

> A family of sets $\mathcal{R}\subset \mathcal{P}(X)$ is called a **ring** if it is closed under finite unions and differences (i.e. if $E_1,\dots,E_n\in\mathcal{R}$, then $\bigcup_{j=1}^n E_j\in\mathcal{R}$, and if $E,F\in\mathcal{R}$, then $E\backslash F\in\mathcal{R}$).  A ring that is closed under countable unions is called a $\sigma$-**ring**.

You need to show two things.  First, that it is closed under complements, and secondly that it is closed under countable unions.

Let $\mathcal{A}=\{E\subset X:~E\in\mathcal{R}~\text{or}~E^c\in\mathcal{R}\}$

Let $E\in\mathcal{A}$.

Then that means $E$ or $E^c$ (possibly both) are in $\mathcal{R}$ by definition of $\mathcal{A}$.

Consider then whether $E^c$ is in $\mathcal{A}$.  $E^c\in\mathcal{A}$ iff $E^c\in\mathcal{R}$ or $(E^c)^c\in\mathcal{R}$.  By the line above, we know one of the two of those to be true, so $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under complement.

Now, for being closed under countable unions:

Let $E_1,E_2,\dots$ be in $\mathcal{A}$.  Then each $E_i$ will be in $\mathcal{R}$ or $E_i^c$ will be in $\mathcal{R}$.  Let $a_i$ be a subindex for those sets that are in $\mathcal{R}$ and $b_j$ be a subindex for those that aren't.  Since $\mathcal{R}$ is a $\sigma$-ring and is closed under countable unions, countable intersections, and differences, you have that

$$\left(\bigcup E_i\right)^c= \left((\bigcup E_{a_i} )\cup(\bigcup E_{b_j})\right)^c = \left((\bigcup E_{a_i})\cup (\bigcap E_{b_j}^c)^c\right)^c = (\bigcup E_{a_i})^c\cap (\bigcap E_{b_j}^c) = (\bigcap E_{b_j}^c)\backslash (\bigcup E_{a_i})  \in \mathcal{R}$$

Therefore $\bigcup E_i\in\mathcal{A}$ by definition of $\mathcal{A}$.

Answer (score 1):

We will prove the following:

> Let $\mathcal{R}$ be a $\sigma$-ring on $X$. Define $$\mathcal{S} := \{E \subset X : E \in \mathcal{R} \text{ or } E^{c} \in \mathcal{R}\}\, ,$$ then $\mathcal{S}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

*Proof:*

- $\mathcal{R}$ is a ring so $\emptyset \in \mathcal{R}$, that means $X^c = \emptyset \in \mathcal{R}$, so $X \in \mathcal{S}$.
- Let $E\in \mathcal{S}$. So there are two possibilities: $E\in \mathcal{R}$ or $E^c\in \mathcal{R}$.

  1. $E\in \mathcal{R}\Rightarrow (E^c)^c\in \mathcal{R}\Rightarrow E^c\in \mathcal{S}$.
  2. $E^c\in \mathcal{R}\Rightarrow E^c\in \mathcal{S}$.
     This means that $\mathcal{S}$ is stable under complements.
- Let $E_1, E_2, E_3, \dots \in \mathcal{S}$. Some $E_j \not\in \mathcal{R}$ but instead $E_j^c \in \mathcal{R}$. We define an index set
  $$J = \{j\in \mathbb{N} : E_j\not \in \mathcal{R}\} .$$
  Then we get $$\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty E_j = \Bigl(\bigcap_{j\in J} E_j\Bigr) \cap \Bigl(\bigcap_{j\in\mathbb{N}\setminus J} E_j \Bigr) = \Bigl(\bigcup_{j\in J} E_j^c\Bigr)^c \cap \Bigl(\bigcap_{j\in\mathbb{N}\setminus J} E_j \Bigr) = \Bigl(\bigcap_{j\in\mathbb{N}\setminus J} E_j \Bigr) \setminus \Bigl(\bigcup_{j\in J} \underbrace{E_j^c}_{\in \mathcal{R}}\Bigr)\, .$$

  Because $\sigma$-rings are $\sigma$-$\cup$-stable, $\bigcup_{j\in J} E_j^c\in\mathcal{R}$.

  $\sigma$-rings are also $\sigma$-$\cap$-stable, so $\bigcap_{j\in \mathbb{N}\setminus J} E_j \in \mathcal{R}$.

  Since rings are $\setminus$-stable we finally get $\bigcap_{j=1}^\infty E_j \in \mathcal{R}$ and so in $\mathcal{S}$.

  We have already proven that $\mathcal{S}$ is stable under complements, that means that $\sigma$-$\cap$-stability and $\sigma$-$\cup$-stability are equivalent (just use De Morgan's laws once more), so we're done. $\square$